# Creating Azure function app against existing consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-app-service-plans

I have created a function app against a new consumption plan with the following command:

```
az functionapp create
    --resource-group myresourcegroup 
    --storage-account mystorageaccount 
    --name myfunctionapp
    --runtime node
    --consumption-plan-location northeurope
```

This creates the function app correctly, but the app service plan is called `NorthEuropePlan`, which does not meet the naming guidelines I am following. I cannot see [anything in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-create) that will allow me to change this name.

Therefore, I would like to create the app service plan before, as a consumption plan (tier `Y1 Dynamic`), and then create a function app against this plan.

```
az resource create
    --resource-group myresourcegroup
    --name myconsumptionplan
    --resource-type Microsoft.web/serverfarms
    --is-full-object
    --properties "{\"location\":\"northeurope\",\"sku\":{\"name\":\"Y1\",\"tier\":\"Dynamic\"}}"
```

That command works correctly, and creates me an app service plan. However, when I try to use that plan (substituting `--consumption-plan-location northeurope` for `--plan myconsumptionplan`), I get this error:

> There was a conflict. AlwaysOn cannot be set for this site as the plan does not allow it.

Do I need to specify some more configuration when I make the app service plan?

When I run `az appservice plan show` against `NorthEuropePlan` and `myconsumptionplan`, the only difference in the object that comes back is the name.

Comment: Is AlwaysOn an option that you can provide for either the function app or the resource?

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons I believe that it's a setting against a Function App, it's on by default and can be turned off through the UI, but only once the Function App is made. I can't see a way to stop it being on by default

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `--plan` I believe the run time will think it is an App Service Plan and will configure `Always ON` which is not allowed in `consumption plan` so I guess you cannot do it like the way you are doing.

You can achieve it with ARM template though. Below is the example command:

```
az group create 
        --name ExampleGroup 
        --location "North Europe"

az group deployment create 
        --name ExampleDeployment 
        --resource-group ExampleGroup 
        --template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-function-app-create-dynamic/azuredeploy.json"
```

The URL mentioned in the `template-uri` is sample template which will create `consumption-pan`, `storage` and `functionapp`.

Deployment will ask the name of parameters (appName) at runtime.